# How to subscribe to changes in the whole gun graph?

Tags: graph, gun

I wonder if there is a way to observe changes in the whole graph, instead of subscribing to changes on one particular node. I was not able to find an answer reading the Docs/Howtos at gun.eco/docs

Lets say you build a real-time mind-mapping application, so basically a graph/tree structure.

1. If I add a new node - at some place - to the graph I want to update my UI
2. If I remove a node or a whole subtree ...

The 2. scenario is a a general concern:

How can I delete multiple nodes together with all related edges ?

Answer (score 3):

Copied from conversation with Gun Community:

First Answer:

To answer the 1st, You could have an index node  that you subscribe to unsing gun.get(node).on(callback, changesOnlyFlag). New nodes would trigger the update function, where you will check what that node might be related to in your application.

To answer the 2nd, Delete in a decentralized system is hard. (Google tombstone problem) In Gun deletes are handled by putting null to an object, which cuts all edges from that item and it becomes unreachable from a traversal standpoint. (Although you can still get the children nodes by their soul (UUID of node), or via the index node that you might add all children too, by default)

Second Answer:

https://gun.eco/docs/API#open describes an additional module you can require to open the whole graph. Which can be used to track changes, with slight modifications to the code.